# Intuition behind these steps?

Tags: matrices, optimization, matrix-calculus

In [publication I am currently studying](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwibxfrz25P2AhXLjIkEHbakDZsQFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fprojecteuclid.org%2Fdownload%2Fpdfview_1%2Feuclid.ejs%2F1352470831&usg=AOvVaw28ZYFhVrDkVK565y5nIY-H), the following identity shows up, and I don't quite understand it. Reformulated from the manuscript, they posit:

$$\min_{\Theta \succ 0}f(\Theta):= -\log \det(\Theta)+\operatorname{trace}(S\Theta) + \lambda||\Theta||_1 \tag{1}$$

where $\Theta$ is a target precision matrix (inverse of a covariance matrix $\Sigma$) we want to estimate, $S$ is a sample covariance matrix (an approximation to $\Sigma$), $\lambda$ is a scalar (a regularization penalty), and $||\Theta||_1$ is the sum of the absolute values of $\Theta$. The authors now state (slightly adapted) the following:

> We use the frame-work of "normal equations". Using sub-gradient
> notation, we can write the optimality conditions (aka "normal
> equations") for the Equation 1 as
>
> $$-\Theta^{-1}+S+\lambda\Gamma \tag{2}=0$$
>
> where $\Gamma$ is a matrix of component-wise signs of $\Theta$.

I am not particularly familiar with this field, and I don't see how this expression follows from the equation above. There is also a mention of "global stationarity conditions of Equation 1". Do you understand how the authors went from Equation 1 to Equation 2, and can offer some intuition about the steps between?

Comment: @little O: Ah, yes, thank you for the heads-up! Fixed.

Comment: Partial explanation: In convex optimization, if $x$ is a minimizer of a convex function $f$, then $0 \in \partial f(x)$, where $\partial f(x)$ is the subdifferential of $f$ at $x$. This is a fundamental optimality condition. Also, the gradient of $-\log \det \Theta$ is $-\Theta^{-1}$. And the gradient of $\text{trace}(S \Theta)$ is $S$. If we can understand the subdifferential of $\lambda \| \Theta \|_1$, then we’re close to deriving an optimality condition for the given optimization problem.

Comment: I’m actually not sure that I agree with equation (2.1) in the paper. I don’t see how the fundamental optimality condition $0 \in \partial f(x)$ becomes a strict equality.

Comment: @littleO: I found another clue. A different paper I came across states that $||\Theta||_1$ can be expressed as $\operatorname{trace}(\Theta\Gamma)$. Using your identity that the gradient of $\operatorname{trace}(S\Theta)$ is $S$, then is this how the third term $\lambda\Gamma$ comes to be?